# How to convert date-time string in to date-time format using sql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to convert a date-time column of type string into datetime format. The columns is in 12-hour format and uses AM and PM to show time.

Here is the input and expected output

```
6/21/2019 2:57:55 PM -> 6/21/2019 14:57:55

6/21/2019 3:12:19 PM -> 6/21/2019 15:12:19

6/21/2019 3:19:31 AM -> 6/21/2019 3:19:31
```

Comment: SELECT STR_TO_DATE('6/21/2019 2:57:55 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %r');  try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `STR_TO_DATE()`

```
select STR_TO_DATE('6/21/2019 2:57:55 PM','%m/%d/%Y %r')
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working for me.

Comment: @MeetPatel, if it helped u please mark it as accepted answer :)